# How can I fix Cplex run configuration error

Tags: cplex

```
int NTasks=...;
 int NStations=...;
 int ct=...;
 int i=...;
 
 
 range Tasks=1..NTasks;
 range Stations=1..NStations;
 
 float T[Tasks]=...;
 int P[Tasks][Tasks]=...;
 
 dvar boolean x[Tasks][Stations];
 dvar boolean y[Stations];
 dvar float+ m;
 
 minimize m==sum(j in Stations)j*y[j];
 
 subject to
{
   
   forall(i in Tasks)sum(j in Stations)x[i][j]==1;
   
   forall(j in Stations)
     sum(j in Stations)T[i]*x[i][j]<=ct;
     
     forall(j in Stations)
       sum(j in Stations)T[i]*x[i][j]<=sum(j in Stations)ct*y[j];
}
```

> hi! I am a beginner in CPLEX.I would try to find cplex code to this article https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00207540701713832 mathematically model to solve this problem SALBP1 but i have a cplex run configuration does not exist error. Do you have any idea to solve this problem or any resources to find something ?

Answer (score 0):

To run a model you need to create a run configuration in the IDE and have the .mod and the .dat in the run configuration

[image: run config]

By the way you can also start with the example given at

https://co-enzyme.fr/blog/simple-assembly-line-balancing-problem-salbp-mip-cp-models-benchmarking/